# Can't Get New GPS Location in Android

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm developing an app that uses Google Map V2 with GPS. The code shows a section where it gets the latitude and longitude of the user's location.

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); //Locate the user's current location

LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
LatLng locationOfUser = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

The app basically uses the value within locationOfUser and can draw a line to the marker that the user selects. This works however when I try the app from a different location the blue marker indicating the user's current location change but the value within locationOfUser didn't and drew the line from the last location not the current one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `requestLocationUpdate`

```
service.requestLocationUpdates(provider, updateInterval, updateDistance, new LocationListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            LatLng locationOfUser = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()); 
        }
    });
```

Where `updateInterval` is the the desire mim time interval and `updateDistance` is the desire min distance interval. You can set updateInterval = 1000 and updateDistance = 1 for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will have to check later to see if this will work

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to manually request location updates from `LocationManager` now that `OnMyLocationChangeListener` interface was added to the API.

You only need to enable the my-location layer (`map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`), set the listener (`map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this)`) and do whatever you want with the current location passed back to you in the corresponding callback (provided by implementing that interface).